# Module export function

Tags: node.js, function, export

I am trying to export a function which sends an email using Sendgrid. I created an external file in which I created this function. The data( credentials used as parameters) I put in other file and I, also, imported it.

I get no errors, but the email is simply not sending.

SEND_MAIL:

```
    module.exports = {

        'sendMail': function(subject, sender_email, email, link, username, template){    
         var request = sg.emptyRequest();
            request.body = {
                subject: subject,
                from: {
                email: sender_email
                },
                personalizations: [
                    {
                      to: [{                     
                         email:  email
                         }],
                      substitutions: {  
                         '[link]'    :  link, 
                         '[email]'   :  email,
                         '[username]':  username
                      }                   
                    }
                ],
                template_id: template 
            };

        request.method = "POST"; 
        request.path = "/v3/mail/send";    
         return sg.API(request).then(function (response) {
             console.log(response);                   
          }).catch(function(err){console.log(err.response.body.errors);});
   }
};
```

THE MAIN FILE (in which I import the function):

```
    var config = require('../config/config.json');
    var utils= require('../service/utils');
    var api_key  = config.sendgrid.key;
    var sg = require('sendgrid')(api_key);

    .....


     function( new_user ){

                var template    = utils.new_account_template;
                var sender_email= utils.new_account_email;
                var link        = utils.new_account_link;
                var subject     = utils.new_account_subject;
                var email       = new_user.email;
                var username    = new_user.username;

                var utilemail = require('../service/utilemail')(subject, sender_email, email, link, username, template);
                utilemail.sendMail(subject, sender_email, email, link, username, template);

return res.json( rs.success({ jwt: new_user.getJwt() }) );

    }).catch(function( err ){
        return res.json( rs.errorCode(err.message) );
    });
```

Comment: Can you post the entire `utilemail.js` file content? For instance, where is `sg` defined there? Where is the closing `};` opened?

Comment: I defined sg in the main file, where I import the utilemail.js file. The entire code from utilemail.js file is available my post. That's all I have there

Comment: Nope, since you call the exported function by `utilemail` (by doing `require('../service/utilemail')(...)`), there should be a part which is missing in your question.

Comment: I have the utilemail. js file in the service folder

Comment: Add the full content of `utilemail.js` in your question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var sendMail= require('../service/utilemail').sendMail;
sendMail(subject, sender_email, email, link, username, template)
.then(function(){
    return res.json( rs.success({ jwt: new_user.getJwt() }) );
}, function(error){
    return res.json( rs.errorCode(err.message) );
})
```

Comment: I tried this before. At your suggestion, I tried it once again, but the very same thing is happening: I get no error (the response is 200 OK), but the email is not sending

Comment: I changed my answer, try it

Comment: yes, it works now. I used it this way:                                               
 var sendMail= require('../service/utilemail').sendMail;
  sendMail(subject, sender_email, email, link, username, template)
  .then(function(){
   return res.json( rs.success({ jwt: new_user.getJwt() }) );
   }).catch(function( err ){
  return res.json( rs.errorCode(err.message) );
 });

Comment: And, also, I added in utilemail.js  these :                                                  
 var config = require('../config/config.json');
var api_key  = config.sendgrid.key;
var sg = require('sendgrid')(api_key);

Comment: Problem was because request finished work before function sendMail call. so don't forget that node.js is asynchronous engine. Always use callbacks or promises ways.